# What's the best regarded way to organize multiple ASP .Net MVC View models within a single view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My app has a main dashboard which is comprised of 8 different partial views; each backed by their own view model and in my controller I'm just calling

```
public ActionResult mainDashboard(){
 return View()
}
```

to return the dashboard. My question is would it be recommended to create a dashboard view model that also contains references to the view models of the partial views? What's considered a recommended best practice in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ohkk here is a good idea as well to use `html.Action` instead of `html.partial`

This would look more like this:

```
public ActionResult Dashboard()
{
    return View();
}

public PartialViewResult Clubs()
{
   ....
    return PartialView(db.Clubs.ToList());//this assumes the partial view is named Clubs.cshtml, otherwise you'll need to use the overload where you pass the view name
}

public PartialViewResult Alerts()
{
   ....
    return PartialView(db.Alerts.ToList());
}
```

Dashboard.cshtml

```
<div class="dashboard_alerts">    
  @Html.Action("Alerts")
```

```
<div class="dashboard_pending_clubs">    
   @Html.Action("Clubs")
</div>

<div class="dashboard_verified_members">    
   @Html.Action("Members")
 </div>
```

**OR**

You would need to create a ViewModel specific for the Dashboard page precisely  this would be more efficient way

```
public class DashboardViewModel
{
  public IEnumerable<GMC.Models.Clubs> Clubs { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<GMC.Models.MemberUsers> Users  { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<GMC.Models.Alerts> Alerts  { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in the Dashboard action method, you would populate each list:

```
myModel.Users = db.MemberUsers.ToList();
```

...
You would then need to update the view to take in this new ViewModel

```
 @model DashboardViewModel
```

Finally, from within the view, you would need to pass in the data to each partial:

```
@Html.Partial("DashboardAlerts", Model.Alerts)

@Html.Partial("DashboardClubs", Model.Clubs)
```

Comment: Glad it helps happy coding :)